# Convert fancybox html to image

Tags: php, html, css, fancybox

I am using `Fancybox` to display a receipt for my clients. Now i want them to be able to download this recipe (for account management).

To do this i thought of generating an image and just allow them to download the image.

Since the data information in the receipt is generated by Ajax i need to be able to take all of the `Fancybox` and convert every HTML, CSS and images onto the image.

So far I've been googling a lot but all i have found are either Java applications or C# applications however these do not for-fill my needs since it has to be PURE web (most likely `PHP`)

Has anyone tried this before or have a solution.

Comment: I'd suggest you use the information on the server to generate a pdf file instead. I don't think an image is appropriate for documents. This PHP library can convert HTML DOM to pdf so it should work well for you. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: If you consider PHP pure web. Then C# is pure web too. I know where your doubts arose though, C# is used to make desktop applications **too**.

Comment: I agree that PDF is more appropriate. As far as i know the only way that you can convert site to image is either make an app that takes screenshot or draw to canvas. It's easier to create a PDF.